# Google Verify account

Tags: frp

I have tried to reset my phone as was given by elder whom the owner is past of which the owner details are not know and I stacked on How to bypass “Verify your account” (Factory Reset Protection) on Nokia 5

Comment: https://www.techeligible.com/2017/10/23/bypass-nokia-google-account

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is directly flash your android phone. 
You can get more detail from XDA. 
You might need to unlock bootloader first.
Than go to download and flash Recovery Image from TWRP. (This is kind of like BIOS on PC)
After that, you can flash a new Android OS without any issue or verify anything.

Or try this: [This may not work]
1. Go to Android Website and download [Android Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)
2. Unzip it and put it in to C:\x
3. Open CMD from windows  (while the phone is connected to your pc)
4. Type:

```
cd c:\x
```

5. Type:
`adb shell settings put secure user_setup_complete 1`
`adb shell settings put global device_provisioned 1`

6. Reboot your phone. (or type adb reboot)